# Dropdown event before droppeddown flag is set

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using a combobox with dropdownstyle: list.
I need to hide the dropdown in-case the user decides to not change the value (particular case).

Problem is when the dropdown event is invoked the combobox droppeddown setting still shows as false. According to the definition of the event `"dropdown": Occurs when the drop-down portion of a ComboBox is shown`.

So shouldn't the "droppeddown" setting be true when the event is invoked?

```
private void comboBoxSelectEntry_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBoxSelectEntry.DroppedDown.ToString());
    if (isChange || isOAWinShown)
        if (MessageBox.Show("Warning: You will loose current session data", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            this.comboBoxSelectEntry.DroppedDown = false;
            return;
        }

    List<string> _data = classes.databank.Anchor.Collection.Where(node => !node.retired).Select(node => node.Name).ToList();
    this.comboBoxSelectEntry.DataSource = null;
    this.comboBoxSelectEntry.DataSource = _data;
}
```

Comment: How about using `selectedIndex` property? If the index is same and not changed, hide it.

Comment: Not sure how would that work. SelectedIndex change will invoke only after user has selected a different value. If i dont hide the dropdown then user can select a value and that will change the selected index.

Comment: this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => comboBoxSelectEntry.DroppedDown = false));  That works but won't thrill you, it is as good as it is going to get.  Redesign your UI to avoid it.

Comment: @HansPassant, very nice workaround, but tricky. Then again, my guess is that the real answer to the question **So shouldn't the "droppeddown" setting be true when the event is invoked?** is still a **no**...

Comment: Definitely a no, it is an "about to drop down" notification.  Most visible from not seeing the dropdown while the message box is displayed.  Would be nice if the native control would have allowed a way to cancel it, so the event could have had the CancelEventArgs argument, but that wasn't the way it was designed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you already provided your answer, it's a 'NO' for your question 'So shouldn't the "droppeddown" setting be true when the event is invoked?'. The `DroppedDown` property is actually set after the droppeddown list is shown. So the event is triggered, but setting the property is just set after the visualization of the contents of the combobox is shown.

Therefore the naming of the event DropDown is correct, it will perform a dropdown event to fire. After fireing (and visualizing the list), the DroppedDown property is set to true and stays this way until the user selects an item.

The MSDN page is actually right, so I guess you can disagree with it, but don't bother. The design back then has been that the DroppedDown property is set only **after** the event has been triggered. Not before.

If you really need that approach, consider a redesign (like Hans Passant mentioned in his comment) of your GUI or create your own control if you have the time for it.

Comment: Actually the page you have pointed to is for the WPF component. I remember trying a testcase for that and the event works as it should. The dropped down property is set when the event is invoked. Even the name of the event is different "DropDownOpened".
Also, I disagree as per MSDN site:"Occurs when the drop-down portion of a ComboBox is shown" which means the dropped down should be shown, and causally the dropped-down flag should be set.

Comment: That is true, I missed the Winforms tag, my apologies. A probable workaround could be to use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event. More info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @RvdV79: You are right. The DropDown event is triggered just before the drop down list is about to be shown. This can be found in [the source code of the ComboBox class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,6a52422b47da7225).

Comment: Yes, I will have to agree to the both of you @R.Beiboer and RvdV79

Comment: Well processing a canceled request after combobox value has changed will require the program to remember the last state and reload it.. (time consuming). 
For now I have worked this around by using mouse_click event. The event is invoked right after the drop-down is shown.